# Clasificar strings por temas en Python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de clasificar unos textos en base a las palabras que contienen.
No sé si habrá alguna forma más eficiente de hacerlo, de ser así y alguien quiere compartirla, ¡será más que bienvenida!

Pongamos un df con 1 columna: Text. Contiene filas con textos, sin más. Todos hablan de una persona, pero sobre distintos temas. A priori sé qué temas son y qué expresiones son las más usuales para referirse a cada uno de ellos. Seguramente hay formas más elegantes e inteligentes de clasificar estos textos (son breves, no más de una o dos frases generalmente, como si fuesen tweets o reseñas breves de productos).

El método que he pensado es el siguiente. Pongo ejemplos de palabras:

```
temas=['programación','enfermeria',"futbol"]

cond=[df['Text'].str.contains(temas,case=False)
      for temas in temas]

df['temas']=np.select(cond,temas,default = 'no')
print(df.temas.value_counts())
```

Con esto, consigo que se cree una nueva columna que es "Temas" donde se pondrá el término que haya encontrado.

El problema es el siguiente: ¿qué pasa si no me interesa TODO lo que se dice sobre programación, sino solamente los textos que hablan de la programación en relación con, por ejemplo, el sueldo? Lo suyo sería poder poner "programación" and "sueldo", por poner un ejemplo, pero no sé como insetarlo dentro de Temas. Y claro, esto querría poder hacerlo (lo de agregar más términos distnitos) para cada profesión, producto o lo que sea.

Además, me parece una solución poco elegante, dado que todo lo escrito en el df sobre programación y los sueldos que no contenga las palabras "programación" y "sueldos" no se recogerá. Por ejemplo, alguien que diga que "los programadores ganan de promedio X€" quedaría fuera, y desde luego es contenido que querría recoger.

Así pues, a priori me iría bien solucionar el tema de como agregar un AND. Si alguien, adicionalmente, puede ofrecer una alternativa para mejorar el proceso... soy todo oídos :)

Muchas gracias!

Un saludo,

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que quieres encontrar una alternativa más adecuada que tu desarrollo actual, para el tratamiento y clasificación de textos por temas. En este caso, mi recomendación es aplicar **NLP**.

NLP (**P**rocesamiento de **L**enguaje **N**atural) es una rama muy extensa de la inteligencia artificial y te permite crear soluciones 'automáticas' a problemas como el que planteas. Intentare hacer un resumen muy básico de algunos pasos que puedes seguir para una solución mejor a la tarea que estás desarrollando.

Python cuenta con varias librerías que facilitan el **procesamiento de textos** como: NLTK, Spacy, Textblob... en la web puedes encontrar muchos blogs con información y ejemplos de uso de varias de ellas ([aquí puedes consultar algunos detalles](https://noeliagorod.com/2019/12/16/top-librerias-de-python-para-nlp/)), y este es el primer paso antes de una **clasificación de textos** (por topics).

Nota: La mayoría de estas librerías funcionan muy bien para textos en ingles y algunas tienen opción de usarse en diferentes idiomas (entre ellos español), con mejores o peores resultados.

Lo habitual en el **procesamiento de texto** (más básico) es:

- Separar el texto en palabras (tokenizar)
- Quitar stopwords: Limpiar palabras vacías que no aportan. p.e: el, la, con, ...
- Otras transformaciones como: pasar todo el texto a minúscula, quitar caracteres 'raros', o puntuación...

Existen muchas otros tipos de procesamiento a aplicar, según lo que busques. Ejemplo:

- Lemmatizar: Estandarizando las palabras a su forma común o lemma (p.e. el lemma para las palabras 'corre' y 'corriendo' sería 'correr').
- Stemming
- NER Chunker
- IOB tagging
- ...

Una vez se ha procesado el texto y se obtiene la lista de palabras 'limpias', puedes usar un modelo LDA que de manera automática clasifica los textos por topics (no por palabras especificas sino por temas). [Aquí un ejemplo de procesamiento con NLTK y clasificación con gensim LDA](https://towardsdatascience.com/nlp-extracting-the-main-topics-from-your-dataset-using-lda-in-minutes-21486f5aa925)

Según la clasificación asignada por el modelo LDA, podrás intentar identificar los grupos de textos y el tema que tienen en común.

Existen muchas otras alternativas tanto técnicas de procesamiento, como modelos aplicables al procesamiento de lenguaje natural, pero es una rama demasiado amplia (que difícilmente se conoce en su totalidad) para lograr cubrirla totalmente en esta respuesta.

Espero que te resulte útil para desarrollar la alternativa de procesamiento correcta para tu texto.

Comment: Hola Eli. Disculpa, veo ahora tu respuesta. Muchas gracias por ella. Lo sé, soy consciente de que lo idóneo es NLP. Sin embargo, no consigo encontrar un corpus en español. Traté de hacerlo con TextBlob, usando su mismo traductor para que lo pasara al inglés y luego me devolviera los resultados, pero al haber demasiadas peticiones me salía un error. Traté de traducirlo, en lugar de con TextBlob, con GoogleTransl, pero me pasaba lo mismo: con pocas filas, bien. Pero con unos cientos no me permite traducir...

Comment: Hola @Marc, Si es viable en tu CU, intenta evitar llamadas al API dentro de un ciclo for (p.e. no llames por tokens sino por texto completo) para reducir el número de llamadas. Sin embargo, algunas librerías como [SpaCy](https://medium.com/datos-y-ciencia/comenzando-con-spacy-para-procesamiento-de-lenguaje-natural-e8cf24a18a5a), te permiten algunos tratamientos en Español. [Aquí](https://relopezbriega.github.io/blog/2017/09/23/procesamiento-del-lenguaje-natural-con-python/)  un ejemplo de nlp para texto en español.